# Why does $\operatorname{Con}(\operatorname{Con}(\Gamma)) = \Gamma$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'll understand if it was

> $\Gamma \subseteq \operatorname{Con}(\operatorname{Con}(\Gamma))$

but why equals? There should be other formulas in $\operatorname{Con}(\operatorname{Con}(\Gamma$)) which aren't part of $\Gamma$.

Edit (lecture notes):

[image]

Comment: If equals, there are **no** formulas in Con(Con($\Gamma$)) that are not part of $\Gamma$...

Comment: In general, the *consequence* relation satisfy: 1) $X \subseteq \text {Con}(X)$ and 2) $\text {Con}(\text {Con}(X))=\text {Con}(X)$.

Comment: A set (of formulas) $X$ is said *closed* iff $\text {Con}(X)=X$.

Comment: My prof said they equal tho. See iii) of edit. Meaning all elements of Con(Con($\Gamma$)) are in $\Gamma$. No more, no less.

Comment: Maybe there is a *definition* of $\text {Con}$ somewhere...

Comment: If so, the Lemma 1 *proves* the three facts and specifically the 3rd one, saying that it is *closed*.

Comment: How does it prove the 3rd one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am certain that this is a typo, and should read "$Con(Con(\Gamma))=Con(\Gamma)$". This is because a closure operator $c$ on a family of sets $\mathcal{F}$ is one satisfying the following three properties:

- $X\subseteq c(X)$,
- $X\subseteq Y$  implies $c(X)\subseteq c(Y)$, and
- $c(c(X))=c(X)$

for all sets $X, Y\in\mathcal{F}$.

In particular, note the "that is" between the statement of the lemma and the three properties: the three properties listed are meant to *define* what a closure operator is.

---

As further evidence for this being a typo, note that as written the properties imply that $Con(X)=X$ for all $X$:

- We have $X\subseteq Con(X)$ and $Con(X)\subseteq Con(Con(X))$ by property $1$.
- But $Con(Con(X))=X$, by property $3$ as your professor wrote it.
- So $X\subseteq Con(X)\subseteq X$, that is, $X=Con(X)$.

So clearly your professor didn't mean to write that, since otherwise $Con$ is trivial!